# React.JS Context API Problem (Rendering Problem)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm currently trying to implement a e-commerce project. My question is about Context API and Reducer.
Cannot able to render price and other details of the product. in Cart Component

Context.Js ;
[Here is my Context.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82HrI.png)

Reducer.Js[Here is the Reducer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sAQX.png)

And My Product Component Code is ;

```
import './Product.css'
import AddBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import { Context } from "./Context"
import React, {useContext} from "react"




function Product({title,price,image,id}) {

   const {addtoBasket} = useContext(Context)

/*
  function alertUser() {
        alert(`${title} added to your card`)
    }

    function addBasket(){
        console.log(title,price)
    }


    function firedFunctions(){
        alertUser()
        addBasket()
    
    }

*/
    
    return (
        <div className="product">
            <div className="product__info">
                <img src={image} alt=""></img>
                <p className="title">{title}</p>
                <div className ="price__add" >
                    <h4>Price : {price} $</h4>
                    <div onClick={() => addtoBasket(title, price, image,id)}>
                    <AddBoxIcon className="btn" />
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

And My Cart Component Code is ;

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import './Cart.css'
import {Context} from "./Context"
import Product from "./Product"


function Cart() {

    const {basket} = useContext(Context)
    console.log(basket) // Expected: Empty Array
    return (
        <div className="cart">
            <div className="cart__left">
                <h2>Your Products</h2>
                    <div>
                        {basket.map((product) =>(                          
                            <h4>{product}</h4>
                            {/*why product give me just a title of product*/}
                                                                     
                        ))}
                        
                    </div>

            </div>
            
            <div className="cart__right">
                <h2>Total</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

[And this is the output when i click the button v.1(console) ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySnUm.png)

[I want to see Price and image either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nik2e.png)

Comment: Offtopic - What's the name of the font in the images you pasted?

Comment: Operator Mono..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing three parameters to `addToBasket` function, however it is receiving just one object.

Probably what you needs is:

```
<div onClick={() => addtoBasket({title, price, image, id)}>
```

I've just replicate it in codesandbox, this is the right answer, take a look:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-violet-fr7np?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Nope, its not for that. Thank you anyways

Comment: in console i can see the output like ;                                                                                    0: {title: "Iphone XS Max", price: 3000, image: "https://cdn.vatanbilgisayar.com/Upload/PRODUCT/apple/thumb/v2-87944-32_large.jpg", id: 2}
 But its not rendering i take a error like : Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, price, image, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: You cant just `<h4>{product}</h4>` like it was, take a look at sandbox I've created

Comment: I saw it.. Appreciated, thank you for your time :)